# Layout preview appearing blank despite of adding items (text boxes etc). Even project name is not appearing on screen

Tags: android

- I created a new project on android studio
- open layout >>  activity_main
- drag and drop text box on layout but still it is empty.

Tried to make font black and edit other settings but nothing helps.

Image

[image]

Comment: can you show your xml text tab with the xml code?

Answer (score 0):

in an android studio, sometimes view not render successfully. so try to re-build the app and clean the project or try text view with a preview for design check widgets show or not